# Heroku / Ruby : Failed to detect set buildpack heroku/ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, buildpack

It is my first time with Heroku and Ruby, so this is probably a noob issue but I can't find any working solution anywhere.  I am following this guide :

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails

I have my app setup, with ruby set as the buildpack, and with this gemfile :

```
## rails 
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.1.5"

## bundler
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'rack', '~>1.1'
gem 'rspec', :require => 'spec'

## heroku
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

## postgresql 
gem 'pg'
```

When I try to push to Heroku with git push heroku master, i receive this error :

```
C:\projects\test\my-app>git push heroku master
Counting objects: 13, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (13/13), done.
Writing objects: 100% (13/13), 2.02 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 13 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Using set buildpack heroku/ruby
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to detect set buildpack heroku/ruby
remote: More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to heroku-who-are-you.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/heroku-who-are-you.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/my-app.git'
```

Here are my Heroku logs.

```
2016-06-09T23:13:31.093017+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started

2016-06-09T23:13:31.093027+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: More info: https://devce
nter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
2016-06-09T23:13:31.093026+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed:
 failed to detect set buildpack heroku/ruby
```

This thing is driving me bananas. Any and all help would be much appreciated !

EDIT: Added Heroku logs

Comment: can you please list the heroku logs?

Comment: @Nirupa Sure, I've added them to the post.

Comment: try running heroku repo:purge_cache -a APPNAME first and then push and make sure you are on master branch. And is everything up-to date on git?

Comment: Also from the above link of devcenter, which section are you exactly following?

Comment: @Nirupa I sorted it out, I was on a develop branch and I didnt realise that git push heroku master was the equivalent of git push heroku master:master

Comment: well yea you need to checkout to master branch to push on heroku. Good luck ahead!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.  I was on my develop branch. Apparently `git push heroku master` defaults to your origin/master branch. Once I merged develop into master and pushed, it worked as expected.

Also, I could have done : `git push heroku develop:master` to specify my develop branch as the source of the push.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to push more than one buildpacks on heroku. If you are not sure about it then you can check if you already have multiple buildpacks set or not by running `$ heroku buildpacks` if heroku/ruby is not on your list then i suggest you to run below command.

```
$ heroku buildpacks:set heroku/ruby
```

then run

```
$ git push heroku master
```